# How to send notification with a delay when a condition is met in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications

I'm creating an app which I want me to send a notification when I'm a certain amount of time awake.

I have done this by calculation the of acceleration the phone and adding this to in total number. This should be some kind of threshold to activate the timer.

I was beable to sent a notification when a button is pressed.

But now I would want to sent this notification when 'accelerationTotalValue > 1000' for example.

Since this is my first project in Android Studio and using java I'm fairly new to all of this.

My java activity

```
public class calibration extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txt_currentAccel, txt_prevAccel, txt_acceleration;
    TextView txt_totalAccel;
    ProgressBar prog_shakeMeter;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private double accelerationPreviousValue;
    private double accelerationTotalValue;

    Button notifyBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calibration_layout);


        // get layout ID's acceleration
        txt_acceleration = findViewById(R.id.txt_accel);
        txt_prevAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_prevAccel);
        txt_currentAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_currentAccel);
        txt_totalAccel = findViewById(R.id.txt_totalAccel);
        prog_shakeMeter = findViewById(R.id.prog_shakeMeter);

        // get info sensors
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        // notification
            // open main page when clicking on notification
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            // find button to activate notification
        notifyBtn = findViewById(R.id.Notification_Button);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification","My Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notifyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(calibration.this,"My Notification");
                builder.setContentTitle("My Title");
                builder.setContentText("This is a simple notification");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_foreground);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(calibration.this);
                managerCompat.notify(1,builder.build());

            }
        });

    }


    // calculation acceleration
    private final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

            double accelerationCurrentValue = Math.sqrt((x * x + y * y + z * z));

            double changeIntAcceleration = Math.abs(accelerationCurrentValue - accelerationPreviousValue);
            accelerationPreviousValue = accelerationCurrentValue;
            accelerationTotalValue = accelerationTotalValue + changeIntAcceleration;

            txt_currentAccel.setText("Current = "+ accelerationCurrentValue);
            txt_prevAccel.setText("Prev = "+ accelerationCurrentValue);
            txt_acceleration.setText("Acceleration change = "+ changeIntAcceleration);
            txt_totalAccel.setText("Total = "+ accelerationTotalValue);

            prog_shakeMeter.setProgress((int)changeIntAcceleration);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put all the stuff that you have in your notifyBtn `onClick` to a separate function, let's call it `notify`, and then add one line in your code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    // Your previous code
    accelerationTotalValue = accelerationTotalValue + changeIntAcceleration;
    if (accelerationTotalValue > 1000) {
        notify();
    }
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Do bear in mind that your current code will only run when your application is in the foreground. I'd suggest reading up on Android's Activity Lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

Comment: Thanks, that works partly. Once accelerationTotalValue > 1000 it keeps creating a notification. It should only sent one. The second issue is that the part that opens the main page when clicking on the notification needs to be in OnCreate but then 'resultPendingIntent' doens't get recognized.

Comment: That's an easy fix with a notified boolean that you set to true when you notify. StackOverflow is not meant for helping you write your code but for specific questions, so please try some things yourself and Google for these new issues that arise - you can find many answers for the things you're dealing with online. Happy coding!